# How to append query strings to the URL in Angular ui-router

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am pretty new to AngularJS. I am using ui-router and node.js as my UI server for API calls to another server. Right now, I am having trouble appending query strings to the URL depending on user input (dropdown selections).

My AngularJS controller code:

```
$scope.getResults = function() {
    server.getResults($scope.myColor, $scope.mySize)
    .success(function(data) {
        results = data;
    });
};
```

AngularJS service for the above function:

```
app.factory('server', ['$http', function($http){
    return { 
        getResults : function(color, size) {
            var req = {};
            req.color = color;
            req.size = size;

            return $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'results',
                params : req
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

ui-router in Angular:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    data:{ 
       pageTitle: 'blah' 
    }
})
```

In Node.js, I have my route like this:

```
app.get("/results", function (req, res) {

    var api = 'some api call/' + req.query.color + '/' + req.query.size;

    request(api, function (error, response, api) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json({
                Color: req.query.color, 
                Size: req.query.size,
                Answer: api
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to have the browser url go from /home to /home?color=Red&&size=Large

Obviously I am not doing this right, the browser url is not dynamic right now. Please show how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use `reloadOnSearch: false` options to stop reloading current route when changes occurs in state parameters.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home?color&size',
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    data:{ 
       pageTitle: 'blah' 
    },
    reloadOnSearch: false //would not refresh state, for location changes.
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getResults = function() {
    //change parameter of URL usingn $location.search.
    $location.search('color', $scope.myColor);
    $location.search('size', $scope.mySize);
    server.getResults($scope.myColor, $scope.mySize)
    .success(function(data) {
        results = data;
    });
};
```

Comment: @jebmarcus Glad to know that. Thanks :-)

Comment: @PankajParker btw the url changes as expected, but when i copy the url and paste it in a new tab, the server doesnt get called like it would normally

Comment: any way to fix that?

Comment: @jebmarcus on initial data call do take parameter from state parameters like `$stateParams.color` & `$stateParams.size` to read those parameter & pass in the ajax call..

Comment: @PankajParker Im a bit confused about what you mean by initial data call. I think the problem here is that the url right now is like this: "http://localhost:3000/#/home?color=Red&size=Large" but im making the return $http I have url: 'results' not 'home

Comment: @jebmarcus I meant to say when your state get loaded.controller instantiated with that state, in controller starting point do `$scope.myColor = $stateParams.color` & `$scope.mySize = $stateParams.size` so while making an ajax, you don't need to worry about passing parameter

Comment: @PankajParker I tried that and now still has the problem. url doesnt actually make any sort of API call. I am going to post a new question and link you

Comment: @jebmarcus URL will not automatically make a call, you need to do it manually. Sure do add new question.. so other people also can participate to help you out.

Comment: please take a look if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670613/how-to-map-url-to-node-js-route