# How to map URL to node.js route

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, url, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router with Angular and Node.js as my UI server for API calls to another server. Right now, my browser URL (dynamic based on dropdown selections) does not map to the server.

For example, the browser URL is "/home?color=Red&&size=Large" when I send the user inputs to Node. When I copy and paste that URL in another browser window, I want the color and size dropdowns to already be selected as Red and Large, and results from API call based on the selections displayed. How can I accomplish this?

My AngularJS controller code:

```
$scope.getResults = function() {

    $location.search('color', $scope.myColor);
    $location.search('size', $scope.mySize);

    server.getResults($scope.myColor, $scope.mySize)
    .success(function(data) {
        results = data;
    });
};
```

AngularJS service for the above function:

```
app.factory('server', ['$http', function($http){
    return { 
        getResults : function(color, size) {
            var req = {};
            req.color = color;
            req.size = size;

            return $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'results',
                params : req
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

ui-router in Angular:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

In Node.js, I have my route like this:

```
app.get("/results", function (req, res) {

    var api = 'some api call/' + req.query.color + '/' + req.query.size;

    request(api, function (error, response, api) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json({
                Response: api
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you wrote query parameters but you need to read them, try this:

```
$scope.getResults = function() {

  $scope.myColor = $location.search().color;
  $scope.mySize = $location.search().size;

  server.getResults($scope.myColor, $scope.mySize)
  .success(function(data) {
    results = data;
  });
};
```

Comment: @sergiy.draunov thanks but it's not binding still. The dropdowns are still all set to blank after doing this

Comment: also this makes the results dissppear